# Find saddle point - C

Tags: c, arrays, file, matrix

I need to find the saddle point of a matrix loading a file with a sequence of numbers. In this case my matrix is 4x3. The sequence of numbers (content of the file) is: 3 -4 8 5 2 7 12 7 9 0 1 2. The functions and some variables are in spanish, I will try to comment everything so you guys can understand it. The thing is that my output is always the same: "the saddle point is in row 0 and column 2" and that´s not true. I'm doing something wrong and I can't spot the problem. Thanks guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 4
#define N 3
int escribeMat(int matriz[M][N]);
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]);
int main()
{
    int numeros, i, j;
    int matriz[M][N];
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\Practicas_TP\\Ficheros\\numeros.txt", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL){
        printf("Error, el archivo no se ha abierto correctamente");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<M;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                fscanf(fichero, "%d", &matriz[i][j]);

            }
        }
        escribeMat(matriz);
        Punto_de_silla_Mat(matriz);
    return 0;
}
}
int escribeMat(int matriz[M][N]){ //function that prints the matrix
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("%3d", matriz[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_fila=0,P_columna=0, encontrado=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        P_fila=i; //row
        P_columna=j; //column
        encontrado=0; //flag
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                P_fila = i;
                P_columna = j;}
        for(k=0;k<N;k++){
            if(matriz[k][P_columna] > matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                encontrado = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
        if(encontrado == 1){
            printf("El punto de silla la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna); //found it + position
        }else
            printf("No hay punto de silla"); //there is no saddle point.

    }
```

Edit 1: Added the missing argument in printf. But still the output should be 7, row 2 and column 1 and I'm getting number 0, row 2 and column 3.

```
printf("El punto de silla es %d y está en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna); //saddle point number + position
```

Edit 2: Removed int numeros. Changed the funtion escribeMat from int to void. Added return to Punto_De_silla function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 4
#define N 3
void escribeMat(int matriz[M][N]);
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]);
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int matriz[M][N];
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\Practicas_TP\\Ficheros\\numeros.txt", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL){
        printf("Error, el archivo no se ha abierto correctamente");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<M;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                fscanf(fichero, "%d", &matriz[i][j]);

            }
        }
        escribeMat(matriz);
        Punto_de_silla_Mat(matriz);
    /*  if(Punto_de_silla_Mat(matriz) == 1){
            printf("El punto de silla es %d y esta en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna);
        }
        else
            printf("No hay punto de silla"); */
    return 0;
}
}
void escribeMat(int matriz[M][N]){ //function that prints the matrix on screen
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("%3d", matriz[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_fila=0,P_columna=0, encontrado=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        P_fila=i; //row
        P_columna=j; //column
        encontrado=0; //flag
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                P_fila = i;
                P_columna = j;}
        for(k=0;k<N;k++){
            if(matriz[k][P_columna] > matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                encontrado = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
        if(encontrado == 1){
            printf("El punto de silla es %d y esta en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna); //saddle point number + position
        }else
            printf("No hay punto de silla"); //there is no saddle point.
            return 0;

    }
```

Still the program is not finding the saddle point.

Edit 3: Swapped M and N at the for loops. Still not getting expected results.

```
int Punto_de_silla_Mat(int matriz[M][N]){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_fila=0,P_columna=0, encontrado=0;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        P_fila=i; //row
        P_columna=j; //column
        encontrado=0; //flag
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                P_fila = i;
                P_columna = j;}
        for(k=0;k<M;k++){
            if(matriz[k][P_columna] > matriz[P_fila][P_columna]){
                encontrado = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
        if(encontrado == 1){
            printf("El punto de silla es %d y esta en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna); //saddle point number + position
        }else
            printf("No hay punto de silla"); //there is no saddle point.
            return 0;
```

Edit 4:
Changed the position of a } in the second for loop. The where two for loops executing at the same time. Nevertheless I'm getting the same wrong result.

Comment: Please watch out for compiler warnings. The results line `printf("El punto de silla esta en la fila %d y en la columna %d", matriz[P_fila][P_columna], P_fila, P_columna);` has 3 arguments but only 2 format specifiers. I guess it should output the data point as well as its location.

Comment: Hang on - why have you changed that? Now nobody will know whether you posted real code or fake code.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just realised, but still the output is no the one I'm expecting.

Comment: Please copy/paste the *exact code* that gives you the claimed result.

Comment: MSVC issues 4 warnings for the code: a) 'numeros': unreferenced local variable, b) 'printf' : too many arguments passed for format string, c) 'escribeMat': must return a value d) 'Punto_de_silla_Mat': must return a value. Although I don't think you are using any supposed return values.

Comment: You have `M` and `N` the wrong way round in the loops in `Punto_de_silla_Mat()` which results in the answer being invalid coordinates.

Comment: Re the edit: you still have `M` and `N` transposed in those loops. It is clear from other functions which way round they should be.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've swapped M and N and still...